# secure curl call - command line calls

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to develop a way for my customer to send me a curl request to get data from my server.  I need this to be psuedo-secure.  I would expect my customer to send me something, I authenticate him, and then wait for him to send me a request for data.  Something like

```
 curl -O 1.2.3.4/curlRequest.php?username=Joe&password=123456790
```

curlRequest.php would verify some credentials.  Clearly sending u/p over get is a terrible idea. any thoughts how i can go about this.  I am not asking anyone to write code for me, Im asking more for what procedures I could use to achieve my goal.

my first thought is to send request 1 that would request some string:

```
  curl 1.2.3.4/authCurl.php?userName=Joe
```

using this and the fact that this request came from a known server, i can respond with a string:

```
 125tewgkljgetEDtstdkj
```

then all future requests must contain that string for the next X minutes:

```
 curl -O 1.2.3.4/curlRequest.php?hash=125tewgkljgetEDtstdkj
```

is this a terrible idea? Any other options that you could recommend?

Comment: at least use post, so their user/pass aren't stuffed into your access_log. disassociate the user from the request - issue an API key (e.g. randomish alpha-numeric string that in no way can be associated back to a particular user except via your database).

Comment: Are you saying that i should customer X should have a key of adsakglsdjglkj and customer y should have a key of lk4yhkljfhdgkjh and just send that every call?

Comment: exactly. that string can be something as simple as `sha1($username . $password . 'randomsaltstringhere')`, but given that asdfasdfasdfasdfasd-type string, there'd be no practical way to get "Joe" back out of it.

Comment: Use HTTPS and send authentication credentials via POST

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to curl, the most secure in your case. The script that will be at the server processes the data from the $ _POST array and create a random manner that will give the key back to the client and for each connection checked his keys ... if the key is not present on the new login and update the key in the database and the client

For more info I can help you with this process. I soon finish a project that runs on the client in the form of the application but is connected to a MySQL database on a remote server ...